# Creating and sending an Outlook meeting request in a .NET/MVC app

Tags: smtp

I am having some difficulty sending an meeting request email using SMTP in my asp.net MVC app. I can send an email no problem, but I can't seem to get it to display as a meeting request.

I have been trying out the solutions posted in other threads but most of them are years old and I can't seem to get them to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.